# Marking GPS coordinates by using accuracy in Android

Tags: java, android, gps, location, coordinates

My problem is about efficiently storing previous locations within a certain radius(determined by accuracy).

`getLatitude()` and `getLongitude()` returns a `double` of coordinates whereas `getAccuracy()` returns a float of meters.

I don't know if there is a conversion that I can find for meters to coordinates but my problem is actually to develop a data structure that can provide fast lookup and manipulation.

First thing that came to my mind is to use something like trie where each number also holds accuracy, but that uses a lot of memory. I will be storing these information in user's device. So it wouldn't be a good way to do.

I thought a bit more about it and only thing that I can think of is I can create dynamic small coordinate plane. E.g user activates the app while at latitude 100.242312, longitude 50.53412 and after each movement, the amount of digits changed determines the size of coordinate plane. Anyway, even this one sounds like overly complex and hard to implement.

My question is, are there any APIs provided for this problem? If not any easy way approach for this problem?

Comment: The Location objects have a method to compare the distance in meters directly. I am not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, though, but it is easy to determine e.g. whether any location is x meters away from the initial starting point

Comment: You mean whether two Location objects overlap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite following what it is that you want to do.

If you only want to store locations after moving a certain distance, then you can simply store  the last location for comparison. Then, later, when the distance between the current position and the stored location exceed the distance threshold, you replace the stored location.

Here is some code showing the idea:

```
public class DistanceFixedImpl extends AbstractStrategyImpl {

private static String TAG = "DistanceFixed"; 
protected int distance;

protected Location lastLocation;


public DistanceFixedImpl(Context context) {
    super(context);
    distance = PreferencesData.getInt(context,
            DistanceBasedFixedDistance.STATE_DISTANCE, 30);
}

/**
 * This is just to enable DistanceAccelerometer, which extends this class, to change what is sent to server
 * 
 * @param TAG
 */
protected void setTAG(String TAG) {
    DistanceFixedImpl.TAG = TAG;
}

public void setLocationStrategyListener(
        LocationStrategyUpdateListener strategyUpdateListener) {
    this.strategyListener = strategyUpdateListener;
}

public void setDistance(int distance) {
    PreferencesData.saveInt(context,
            DistanceBasedFixedDistance.STATE_DISTANCE, distance);
    this.distance = distance;
}

@Override
public void startStrategy() {
    startUsingGPS();
    strategyListener.strategyMessageCallback("Awaiting GPS first-fix"); 
}

@Override
public void stopStrategy() {
    stopUsingGPS();
    super.stopStrategy();
}

@Override
public void onFirsFixChanged(boolean hasGPSfix) {
    strategyListener.strategyMessageCallback("Received a first-fix change to: " + hasGPSfix);
}

private Integer[] outputPercentages = new Integer[]{25,50,75,100};
private int outputPercentIndex;

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    incrementLocationChangesOnDevice();
    // ignore any incomming locations as long as first fix is not set
    if (!hasFirstFix())
        return;

    if (lastLocation == null) {

        /**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- *
         *  No location to compare against yet, so we just save it as two is needed to calculate distance * 
         * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        lastLocation = location;
        sendLocationToServer(location, TAG);
    } else {
        float distanceMoved = lastLocation.distanceTo(location);

        int outputDistancePercent = outputPercentages[outputPercentIndex];
        if ((distanceMoved/distance)*100 >= outputDistancePercent) { 
            outputPercentIndex = (outputPercentIndex+1) % 4;
            strategyListener.strategyMessageCallback("Moved: " + outputDistancePercent + "% of " + distance + " meters");
        }

        if (distanceMoved > distance) {

            // threshold exceeded - send location to server

            strategyListener.strategyMessageCallback("SEND: " + distanceMoved
                    + " meters");

            sendLocationToServer(location, TAG);

            lastLocation = location;

        } 

    }
}

}
```

The above code is part of a project I made for a Pervasive Positioning course.

If this is what you want to implement, then I can provide a link for the project source code.

Comment: Not quite what I want.
I am simply making a utility tool and it will use coordinates to enable/disable services. My intention is for instance user will select their location as home and leave it as home while the user is at home. Once user leaves home user will de-select home, so next time by using the previous locations that I have gathered, I want to be able to determine that the user is at home or not.

Comment: Well, in theory you could use this idea for that too. Instead of comparing current location against lastLocation, then you would compare against all the saved locations. That way you would know the distance to for example home and whether to select or deselect it.

Comment: I cannot really follow your code, where exactly are you doing the comparison?

Comment: In onLocationChanged at distanceMoved > distance, distance being a predefined threshold

Comment: So basically, what I am looking for is a list of lastLocation.distanceTo(location)?

Comment: Something like that, yes. lastLocation in your case being something like tagged locations. So you have a list of tagged place like home, work etc.. and then simply get the distance between the current location and the tagged locations.